# lazy var: Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value

Tags: swift

At the line, `dateFormatter.string(from: date)`, the compiler says:

> Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable
> Mark method 'mutating' to make 'self' mutable

```
struct viewModel {
    
    private lazy var dateFormatter = { () -> DateFormatter in
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var labelText: String? {
        let date = Date()
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

I understand what is written in [this](https://oleb.net/blog/2015/12/lazy-properties-in-structs-swift/) link, but the above situation is probably different.

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: Why is it lazy in the first place? Do you really need lazy for creating a date formatter?

Comment: Lets just say my struct has many more properties and as creating DateFormatter is an expensive operation I want it to be lazy.

Comment: @AnandKumar Is it, though?

Comment: @Alexander Creating NSDateFormatter did used to be expensive. http://www.chibicode.org/?p=41

Comment: @AnandKumar Now imagine a more realistic situation where creating the date formatter is say, 5% of the work, then all of a sudden you'll notice that the relative time increase will be tiny

Comment: @AnandKumar And for the record, we're suggesting you don't create a static variable for this data formatter. We're just saying there's no need for it to be `lazy`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need a mutating getter in order to perform mutations on `self` (such as accessing a lazy variable).

```
struct ViewModel {
    private lazy var dateFormatter = { () -> DateFormatter in
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
        return formatter
    }()

    var labelText: String? {
        mutating get {
            let date = Date()
            return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is clever (I upvoted :-)), unfortunately, all 'instances' of such a struct have to be mutable, which could be counterproductive. In this case, I would prefer to define ViewModel as a class

Comment: @user3441734 I would do that too, if I had to use lazy vars. But this case really has no need for lazy vars at all.

Answer (score 12):

Accessing a lazy property on a struct **mutates the struct** to save the new property value on the struct, same as if you were changing a `var` variable on that property.

So you are not allowed to use `lazy var` in any circumstance where re-assigning the `var` after `init` would not be allowed.

This is rather unintuitive, as using `lazy var` doesn't "feel" like it is mutating the struct after assignment. But when you think about it, that's exactly what's happening.